# Logging and Replaying database updates/inserts SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am in the process of migrating our client's database to the Azure Cloud SQL Server and setting up data sync etc. All of this is ok, but I need to reduce the amount of time the client's system needs to be down for to complete this process.

I was hoping to be able to set up a process that records all database inserts/updates from the time I create the backup which will be used in to migrate the data to azure, and then replay them on the database once it's in the cloud.

Is there a tool for this? Is SQL Profiler good enough for this?

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server, and how many tables are in the database? If you're on Enterprise with not too many tables, [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) might be a good option.

Comment: When you say azure cloud, is it windows sql azure or sql server running on windows virtual server ? That makes a huge difference as the former has some limitations with T-sql.

Comment: @JonSeigel 100 or so tables, SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, looking into it thanks.

Comment: @Kin it's Windows SQL Azure

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this off, I found that [Red gate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) seems to be a great tool that will allow me to simply compare the two databases and in essence replicate the differences.

Comment: Yep, that works, too, if the database is small enough you can afford to scan both copies of it. I suppose I should have asked about that. Actually now that I think about it, you could use Visual Studio if you have the appropriate licence level for it, which may mean you don't have to buy anything new.